# Can't Find Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm trying to create a custom search result webpart, and I need to develop a class that must inherit Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart. However, when I add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Server, I just can use Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.PortalCrawl. Searching for solutions on internet, I found just one person who had the same problem, and nobody answered him. Does anyone has any idea of why I can't load the correct namespaces and where on earth this PortalCrawl came from?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same issue sometime back...

While adding reference it will be listed as 'Microsoft® Search component' under .NET components.

There will be two dlls with same component name  (mentioned above).

- Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.dll   (This is the one you need)
- Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Connector.dll

Answer (score 0):

The assembly you need to reference is Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.dll

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.webcontrols.coreresultswebpart.aspx)